# How to calculate bigquery row size?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using bigquery streaming api(java) to insert data, and realized there is a size limitation of 1MB on table row, but does anyone know more about this limitation, like how this 1MB was calculated? (I guess it shouldn't be the size of TableRow object). Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

data size is calculated based on the size of each data type.

```
Data type   Size
STRING      2 bytes + the UTF-8 encoded string size
INTEGER     8 bytes
FLOAT       8 bytes
BOOLEAN     1 byte
TIMESTAMP   8 bytes
RECORD      0 bytes + the size of the contained fields
```

see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#datafor more details

Comment: Hi, I just want to double check if my calculation is correct. I am using streaming insert in Python https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-table-insert-rows. If I insert this json object: data = {'event': 'signup', 'email': 'abc@email.com'}. To calculate the size, should I stringify the json object and multiply the string length by 2 bytes like this: len(json.dumps(data)) * 2 bytes = total size?