# BigQuery Streaming Insert - Estimate insertion size in to avoid limitations exceeded

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

After trying to insert rows with Streaming, I've encountered the following issue:

> Request payload size exceeds the limit: 10485760 bytes.

Is there a way to estimate a row size after building it?

I create a list of `BigQueryInsertRow` objects and then use the client `InsertRows` method for insertion, I don't find any `GetSize()` or any other method to estimate the row size that will be uploaded to BQ.

Although there's a way to iterate over the columns values, I don't know how the BQ V2 Nuget is calculating this size.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40855461/how-to-calculate-bigquery-row-size

Comment: Thanks, I wrote my on code for this, I'd share it but it depends on large internal classes and its not copy/paste code - because `BigQueryInsertRow` do not contain the target DB Type. I think Google should release this feature at their Nuget package.